# SSO login in NiFi version 1.4 using OIDC

Tags: properties, authorization, single-sign-on, apache-nifi

I want to enable SSO login in NiFi version 1.4 in my Compute Engine in GCP using OIDC. I want to allow all users from my Azure Active Directory group that I have made before to be able to login to NiFi using their account as registered. But I can't seem to make it work.

I have followed this step: https://github.com/benkelly/NiFi-Authentication-with-Azure-Active-Directory-Setup-Guide

But, I'm stuck at this error :
[image]

This is my configuration:

nifi.properties

```
# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populat>
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.s>
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=20 secs
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.password=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key=
nifi.flowfile.repository.retain.orphaned.flowfiles=true

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=7 days
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.password=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key=

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.password=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key=

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=30 days
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=10 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=10 mins
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false

# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uui>
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is re>
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component and Node Status History Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentSt>

# Volatile Status History Repository Properties
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# QuestDB Status History Repository Properties
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.node.days=14
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.component.days=3
nifi.status.repository.questdb.persist.location=./status_repository

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
#############################################

# For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
# Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
# We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

#############################################
nifi.web.https.host=<IP>
nifi.web.https.port=<my port>
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=<proxy IP>
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# Include or Exclude TLS Cipher Suites for HTTPS
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.include=
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.exclude=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=<key>
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.p12
nifi.security.keystoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=<key store>
nifi.security.keyPasswd=<key pass>
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.p12
nifi.security.truststoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=<pass>
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.initial.admin.identity=admin@astrapay.com
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my client ID>/v>
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=<my client ID>
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=<my client secret>
#nifi.security.user.oidc.use.jwks.endpoint=true
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=profile, email, openid
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=upn
nifi.security.user.oidc.redirect.uri=https://<IP:port>/nifi-api/access/oidc/callback
nifi.security.user.oidc.enabled=true
# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.missable.max=8
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=1
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
nifi.zookeeper.client.secure=false
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststorePasswd=

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster manage>
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerber>
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=
# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeas>
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90

# runtime monitoring properties
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.schedule=
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.threshold=
```

authorizer.xml

```
<authorizers>
    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">email admin</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
    </userGroupProvider>

   <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>aad-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.azure.AzureGraphUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Refresh Delay">5 mins</property>
        <property name="Authority Endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com</property>
        <property name="Directory ID">directory ID</property>
        <property name="Application ID">client ID</property>
        <property name="Client Secret">client secret</property>
        <property name="Group Filter Substring">NiFi-AAD</property>
        <property name="Page Size">100</property>
        <property name="Claim for Username">email</property>
    </userGroupProvider>

    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>composite-configurable-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.CompositeConfigurableUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Configurable User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="User Group Provider 1">aad-user-group-provider</property>
    </userGroupProvider>

    <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>composite-configurable-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">email admin</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>

    <authorizer>
        <identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Access Policy Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
    </authorizer>
</authorizers>
```

When I start my NiFi in SSH, I get this error instead:

```
2023-11-02 04:37:15,839 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Graph service exception Error code: Authorization_RequestDenied
2023-11-02 04:37:15,840 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
2023-11-02 04:37:15,841 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2023-11-02 04:37:15,842 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?%24select=displayName&%24top=100
2023-11-02 04:37:15,842 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
2023-11-02 04:37:15,843 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
2023-11-02 04:37:15,843 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2023-11-02 04:37:15,844 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2023-11-02 04:37:15,845 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220403 : Forbidden
2023-11-02 04:37:15,845 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[...]
2023-11-02 04:37:15,846 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2023-11-02 04:37:15,847 ERROR [main] global CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
2023-11-02 04:37:15,847 ERROR [main] global Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?%24select=displayName&%24top=100
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]

403 : Forbidden
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
2023-11-02 04:37:16,072 ERROR [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJwtAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Failed to load UserGroup due to Error code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```